# How can I get the sum of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops, sum

I'm trying to sum up all of the elements in an array.
What do I need to put in for blank space of `int i = ______;` to make this work?

```
public static int sumArray(int [] A){

        int sum = 0;
        int i = ___________ ;
        while(i>=0){
            sum = sum + A[i];
            i--;
        }return sum;

    }
```

Comment: It should be `int i = A.length - 1;`, refer to my answer for other alternatives to iterating through an `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to sum up all of the elements in an array. What do I need to put in for blank space of 'int i = ______;' to make this work?

You should specify the size of array `A` to `i` by doing `i = A.length - 1;`.

Alternatively, you can use a `for` loop instead of `while`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static int sumArray(int [] A){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int x : A) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you should set `int i` to `A.length - 1`. You want `length - 1` because `Arrays` are indexed at 0 which means using `length` alone will cause you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Your method should look like this:

```
public static int sumArray(int[] A) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i = A.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        sum = sum + A[i];
        i--;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

*However*, you can do this in much more cleaner ways.

1) Using Java 8 you can use `IntStream` like so:

```
public static int sumArray(int[] A) {
    return IntStream.of(A).sum();
}
```

2) You can use a `for` loop:

```
 public static int sumArray(int[] A) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
      sum += A[i];
      }
     return sum;
 }
```

3) You can use an enhanced `for` loop:

```
public static int sumArray(int[] A) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : A){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already written the code to get the sum. `i` just needs to start out at `A.length`.

There are many other ways to get the sum: using an enhanced "for each" loop; using `IntStream.of(A).sum()`; other library methods.